# Mysql, Show who has and hasn't opted out of bus service

Tags: mysql

I have student and event tables linked by sid.

```
 CREATE TABLE `students` (
`sid` int(8) NOT NULL COMMENT 'use',
`active` enum('Yes','No','vac','Grad') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Yes',
`name` varchar(130) DEFAULT NULL,
`bus` varchar(130) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `students` (`sid`, `LEFT(name, 2)`, `bus`) VALUES
(51, 'Me', 'BusA'),
(52, 'Hi', 'BusA'),
(59, 'An', 'BusA'),
(70, 'Mi', 'BusB'),
(100, 'Yu', 'BusB');

CREATE TABLE `STATevent` (
  `eventid` int(24) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `level` enum('absent','bus') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Percent` tinyint(5) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(266) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `STATevent` (`eventid`, `sid`, `date`, `created`, `level`, `color`, `Percent`, `note`) VALUES
(43, 59, '2022-11-30 21:17:04', '2022-11-28 12:17:04', 'bus', 'red', 100, '');
```

The student can select not to get bus service, which shows as an entry (like eventid 43 above).  I can get the list of 'bus students', along with an id to show who cancelled service and who hasn't.

```
SELECT C.name, C.sid, O.sid AS 'bid', C.bus FROM students C
LEFT JOIN STATevent O ON  C.sid = O.sid
WHERE C.bus LIKE 'Bus%' AND C.active = 'Yes' ;
```

However, when I try to limit *where* with the date, the result shows only the one who cancelled service.

```
SELECT C.name, C.sid, O.sid AS 'bid', C.bus FROM students C
LEFT JOIN STATevent O ON  C.sid = O.sid
WHERE C.bus LIKE 'Bus%' AND C.active = 'Yes' AND O.date LIKE '2022-11-29%';
```

How can I add this limiter and get the full results like the first query?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So every entry in STATevent means that the student does not use a service, and all students that have a bus flag like 'bus%' and no entry in the table at a point of time do use the bus service? And for a given timestamp, you want to show all students who use the bus service then?

Comment: Side notes: The `date` column is of time `datetime` (not a date, despite its name) and not a string. So, don't apply string functions (`LIKE`) on it. Use date/datetime functions. Why must you check the bus column for a pattern starting with 'bus'? Can a bus column contain anything else than a bus? And is this pattern matching the only way to learn whether the student uses the bus? There should be a better way to model this.

Comment: Because this field is either 'busA' and 'busB', or 'no'. This way, each bus can get it's own list of who to pick up.  But, for this example, I'm just looking them all up as a masterlist.

Comment: So, people opt for the bus, but they get sick, etc and have to cancel.  So, I'm creating this system where they'll each have a 'button' to click and that creates the event entry.
For the driver (which this list is for) he just sees an updated list of who not to pick up on that day.  This is why the date is given.  It will be possible for the person to cancel days ahead of time, as well.  This beats them calling me at 9pm on a Saturday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may move the restriction on the event date to the `ON` clause of the left join:

```sql
SELECT c.name, c.sid, o.sid AS bid, c.bus
FROM students c
LEFT JOIN STATevent o
    ON o.sid = c.sid AND
       DATE(o.date) = '2022-11-29'
WHERE c.bus LIKE 'Bus%' AND c.active = 'Yes';
```

For students who did *not* cancel service, the `bid` would be reported as null.

Answer (score 1):

You want to show all students that use a bus servvice, but exclude those that opt out for a certain date. You can use `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` to do this lookup.

```
SELECT *
FROM `students`
WHERE bus LIKE 'Bus%' AND active = 'Yes'
AND sid NOT IN
(
  SELECT sid
  FROM `STATevent`
  WHERE DATE(date) = DATE '2022-11-30'
)
ORDER BY sid;
```

If you want to show all potential bus service users instead with a flag whether they attend that day or not, you can move the condition to the select clause:

```
SELECT s.*
  sid IN
  (
    SELECT sid
    FROM `STATevent`
    WHERE DATE(date) = DATE '2022-11-30'
  ) AS opt_out
FROM `students` s
WHERE bus LIKE 'Bus%' AND active = 'Yes'
ORDER BY sid;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/TxyzF564

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification. I was using the NOT IN option before, but then ran into the snag of not seeing all of them. This way there can be graphics showing who to skip, instead of deciphering who isn't in the list.